# Print the number of times the string occured in a loop?

Tags: java, string, loops

I'm really new to Java...

Output:

```
Input Number= 0919-FOREKEY

Your telecommunication company is SMART.
Your phone number is 0919-2255633.
Continue Y/N: Y

Input Number=0922-KORELEY
Your telecommunication company is SUN
Your phone number is 0922-2255633.

Continue Y/N: N

--------------------------------------------------------
Thank you for using the program !

SMART : 1
GLOBE : 2
SUN CELL: 0
```

Here's my code

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    boolean deci=false;

    PhoneKeyPad pad=new PhoneKeyPad();

    do
    {

        String telco=pad.getTelcoProvider("Enter 09XX-NUMBERS: ");
        boolean condition=false;

        if (telco.length()>12)
        {
            System.out.println("Input must be 12 characters only");
        }

        String telcom=telco.substring(0,4);
        String smart1="0919";
        String smart2="0920";
        String globe1="0927";
        String globe2="0917";
        String sun1="0922";
        String sun2="0933";

        if ((smart1.equals(telcom)) || (smart2.equals(telcom)))
        {
            System.out.println("Your telcom company is Smart");
        }
        if ((globe1.equals(telcom)) || (globe2.equals(telcom)) )
        {
            System.out.println("Your telcom company is Globe");
        }
        else if((sun1.equals(telcom)) || (sun2.endsWith(telcom)) )
        {
            System.out.println("Your telcom company is Sun");
        }

        String first=telco.substring(5,6);
        String firstOutput=pad.convertMobile(first);
        System.out.print(" "+first);

        String second=telco.substring(6,7);
        String secondOutput=pad.convertMobile(second);
        System.out.print(" "+second);

        String third=telco.substring(7,8);
        String thirdOutput=pad.convertMobile(third);
        System.out.print(" "+third);

        String fourth=telco.substring(8,9);
        String fourthOutput=pad.convertMobile(fourth);
        System.out.print(" "+fourth);

        String fifth=telco.substring(9,10);
        String fifthOutput=pad.convertMobile(fifth);
        System.out.print(" "+fifth);

        String sixth=telco.substring(10,11);
        String sixthOutput=pad.convertMobile(sixth);
        System.out.print(" "+sixth);

        String seventh=telco.substring(11,12);
        String seventhOutput=pad.convertMobile(seventh);
        System.out.print(" "+seventh);

        System.out.println("\nYour number is "+telcom+"-"+firstOutput
                     +secondOutput+thirdOutput+fourthOutput+fifthOutput+sixthOutput+
                     seventhOutput);
        System.out.println("Do you want to continue Y/N");
        String decisionFinal=pad.decisionFinal("");
        if ((decisionFinal.equals("N")))
        {
            deci=false;
            break;  
        }

        deci=true;

    }

    while (deci=true);
        System.out.println("Smart: "+smart);

        System.out.println("Thank you for using the program");

}
```

Comment: Million dollar quesion... What IS Your Question?

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize the `boolean deci` with `true`. That way you don't need to bother making it true at the end of the loop. In the if statement at the bottom, it takes care of exiting the loop with the `deci = false`. You don't even need the `break`. The loop will automatically exit because of the `while` condition. And your `while` condition is wrong. the `=` should be a double `==`. `=` is an assignment operator, while `==` is a comparison operator. Better yet, you can just use `while(deci)`, which translate to `while(deci == true)`.

Try this

```
boolean deci = true;

do {
    ...
    if ((decisionFinal.equals("N")))
    {
        deci = false;  
    } 

    // delete deci=true; 

} while (deci);
```